# Find the linearization of the following curves at a suitably chosen integer near a

Tags: calculus, linearization

Find the linearization of the following curves at a suitably chosen integer near a 
$f(x) = x^2 + 2x$

$a=0.1$

in this i used the formula $L(x)=f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$ and solved and got $L(x)=2.2x-0.01$

is it right or am i misinterpreting the question?

Comment: Please put your title in the question as well.

Comment: Giving a full problem statement in the body of your Question is especially important when you ask "am i misinterpreting the question?".  The formula is right, but I have not checked your result.

Comment: @TobyMak done now in edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f(x) = x^2 + 2x
$$
therefore
$$
f^{'}(x)=2x+2.
$$
Given a differentiable function f defined near a, the linearization of f at a is the linear function given by $L(x) = f(a) + f^{'}(a)(x − a)$.

Now we have:
$$
L(x) = f(a) + f^{'}(a)(x − a)=0.21+2.2(x-0.1)=2.2\cdot{x}-0.01.
$$

Yes, you are right.